# paypal download account activity history

Tags: python, paypal

I would like to download the account activity history of my Paypal account.
Like described here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/download-history/

I would like to do this with Python.
I tried to use the REST API to get the history:

```
payment_history = paypalrestsdk.Payment.all({"count": 10})
payment_history.payments
```

This delivers an empty list.
I guess it accounts only historic payments processed with the REST API.

I just want to get my private account history. Is there a possibility using an API?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: The document you linked to is not for the REST API. It's for manually downloading a file. If there is nothing in the API documentation about this, then you can't do it.

Comment: Yes, this is the information I would like to access via an API. I do not want to download this information manually if it is possible...